# Need advice on how to speed up web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, beautifulsoup

I am still pretty new to this. I am trying to pull data from web pages, but this method I have implemented seems a bit slow. I used the time module to narrow down the cause of the lag.

```
requests.get(url)
```

took the majority of the time (1-5 seconds)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
```

took about 0.15 seconds consistently

Is requests always this slow? Is the problem that yahoo rate-limits requests from their servers? Right now it is taking around 2-5 seconds to pull a single stock price from yahoo.com/finance and requests is the major problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not with Reqeusts. If it's slow it might be an issue with your net connection. It might also be that yahoo rate-limits requests as you rightly pointed out. Each website has a robots.txt file that details their policies regarding web scrapers and automated access to them.
It shouldn't take so long regardless but I would put it down to an internet speed problem. Try to access the URL from your browser and check how long it takes to load up.

A GET request is what you send a website when you want to "GET" a webpage from them. The same GET is used when you enter the URL into your browser and hit enter. So unless there is a marked difference between the time it takes Requests to get the page and the time it takes your browser to get the page it's a problem with the internet connection speed itself.

Comment: When you use requests.get(url), is that speed to retrieve the source code the same speed at which my browser would load the data and display it?

Comment: Yes because they both employ the GET method which is consistent across all platforms.

Comment: Also, yes my internet speed isn't great right now, I'll try it later on a faster connection.

Comment: So all programs, across all languages, use a GET request to interact with the server?

Comment: Here's a link explaining how GET is an HTTP Request Method. Http is a standard protocol hence all implementations of it will be consistent irrespective of the platform.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: No, there are various other methods as well, significant among them is the POST method. What I mean is irrespective of language or platform, the implementation of the GET method will be the same.

Comment: So calling the equivalent of requests.get(url) for different languages will take the same amount of time. The browser calls the GET method as well internally but the implementation of how GET goes about it's work is the same. Inherent language differences are very negligible, lower level languages like C/C++ will give you better times but not significantly since they are on your end of things. It won't affect how long it takes GET to retrieve the webpage. It'll make the calling of the GET method slightly faster.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to what Meghdeep said..

If you are pulling many urls in sequential order you should try rewriting your code to be asynchronous. The time it takes to scrape one page will not change, but asynchronously you could scrape many pages at once. (You can use the Python Twisted or Tornado frameworks for this..or you can rewrite your scraper with Node.js)

Comment: Ok, I'll look into asynchronous scraping. Again, I'm still new to this

Comment: No worries. We were all "new to this" at some point. And that's what StackOverflow is for. :)

Comment: Just a note on this : Do look up the Robots.txt for a specific site before doing this so you can see what the maximum number of connections is. Assuming he'll be scraping multiple yahoo finance pages, there's a chance he exceeds the permitted connections and yahoo shuts him out. (temporarily of course)

Comment: Hey guys, so I moved to a faster internet connection, but now I am getting an error: WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

Comment: I guess this is some sort of encoding thing just by doing a little research, but it is not sending me back html anymore, so Beautifulsoup is returning a None type when I try to find the <span> tag

Comment: What is the output of `print(data.content)` ?